# Super Contest Winners: Week 1

Tags: discussion, super-contest

This post is to document the **week 1** winners of the [Super User Super Contest](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/super-user-1-year-anniversary-super-contest/), for the week ending **Monday, August 30**.

Congratulations to our winners this week!

1. [Best rookie](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/week/superuser/2010-08-23) performance by [**KronoS**](https://superuser.com/users/47225/kronos)

   [image: best rookie performance week of 08-23-2010]
2. [Highest reputation](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/week/superuser/2010-08-23) produced by [**digitxp**](https://superuser.com/users/23420/digitxp)

   [image: top users week of 08-23-2010]
3. Best meta post:

   [Is there any point answering questions that have had no recent activity?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1324/is-there-any-point-answering-questions-that-have-had-no-recent-activity) by [**boot13**](https://superuser.com/users/41423/boot13)
4. Most awesome new question or answer:

   [Should I unmount a USB drive before unplugging it?](https://superuser.com/questions/180722/should-i-unmount-a-usb-drive-before-unplugging-it) by [**systempuntout**](https://superuser.com/users/38035/systempuntoout)

We are contacting the winners now, so be sure to check your email inboxes!

Comment: Congrats to all the winners, let this be an encouragement for all the 'losers'!

Comment: Typo: systempunto **o** ut

Answer (score 9):

Congrats to the winners :D